# Is there a better way to organize this behaviour as a collection of traits?

Tags: struct, rust, signal-processing, traits

I'm putting together an audio dsp and I'm looking for a more "rustacean" way to implement the following:

```
pub struct TransformOptions<SourceType> {
    transform         : Option<Box<dyn Fn(&mut [SourceType; FFT_SIZE], &mut [SourceType; FFT_SIZE])>>,
    filter            : Option<Box<dyn Fn(&mut [SourceType; FFT_SIZE], [SourceType; FFT_SIZE])>>,
    inverse_transform : Option<Box<dyn Fn(&mut [SourceType; FFT_SIZE], &mut [SourceType; FFT_SIZE])>>
    //should try anddo this in an array
    //options           : [Option; NUM_TRANSFORM_OPTIONS],
}

impl<SourceType : Default> TransformOptions<SourceType> {
    fn cycle_through(&self, input : [SourceType; FFT_SIZE])->[SourceType; FFT_SIZE] {
        //let input : [T ; FFT_SIZE] = arr![T; FFT_SIZE];
        //This represents the amplitude of the signal represented as the distance from the origin on a unit circle
        //Here we transform the signal from the time domain to the frequency domain.
        //Note that humans can only hear sound with a frequency between 20Hz and 20_000Hz
        // fft.process(&mut time_ring_buffer[time_index..time_index + fft_size], &mut complex_freq_buffer[..]);
        if  let Some(_) = self.transform{
            let transform_func = self.transform.unwrap();
            let output = input.clone();
            transform_func(&input, &output);
            input = output;
        }
        //the analytic array acts as a filter, removing the negative and dc portions
        //of the signal as well as filtering out the nyquist portion of the signal
        //Also applies the hamming window here

        // By applying the inverse fourier transform we transform the signal from the frequency domain back into the
        if  let Some(_) = self.filter {
            let filter_func = self.filter.unwrap();
            /*
               this is roughly how it should go down
               | input, coefficient | {
               for input_idx in index.ter() {
                    input_idx = input_idx * coeffcient[input_idx.index];
               }
               }
            */
            input = filter_func(&input);
        }
        // By applying the inverse fourier transform we transform the signal from the frequency domain back into the
        // time domain. However now this signal can be represented as a series of points on a unit circle.
        // ifft.process(&mut complex_freq_buffer[..], &mut complex_analytic_buffer[..]);
        if  let Some(_) = self.inverse_transform {
            let transform_func = self.inverse_transform.unwrap();
            let output = input.clone();
            transform_func(&input, &output);
            input = output;
        }
        input
    }
}
```

Essentially what I'd like to do is have some sort of trait which collects some subtraits and checks if they are implemented on this struct. If they are then it was call their respective top level function and pass data through appropriately. I'm not sure if there is a better way to accomplish this than what I have currently.

Edit: Something like this is what I'm shooting for
Is it possible/advisable to do something like this ?

```
trait Transform {
    fn transform(&self, &mut [SourceType; FFT_SIZE], &mut [SourceType; FFT_SIZE]) {
        // default implementation does nothing
    }
}

trait InverseTransform {
    fn filter(&self, &mut [SourceType; FFT_SIZE], [SourceType; FFT_SIZE]) {
        // default implementation does nothing
    }
}

trait InverseTransform {
    fn inverse_transform(&self, &mut [SourceType; FFT_SIZE], &mut [SourceType; FFT_SIZE]) {
        // default implementation does nothing
    }
}
trait TransformOptions {
    //Check for and use the above traits in here somehow. Leaving room for implementation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a trait somewhat like this:

```
trait TransformOptions {
    fn transform(&self, &mut [SourceType; FFT_SIZE], &mut [SourceType; FFT_SIZE]) {
        // default implementation does nothing
    }
    fn filter(&self, &mut [SourceType; FFT_SIZE], [SourceType; FFT_SIZE]) {
        // default implementation does nothing
    }
    fn inverse_transform(&self, &mut [SourceType; FFT_SIZE], &mut [SourceType; FFT_SIZE]) {
        // default implementation does nothing
    }
}
```

Then, each implementor can decide itself if it wants to actually do work in `transform`, `filter` and `inverse_transform`. Then, instead of checking if a function is present, you simply call it, and it potentially is a no-op.

Comment: Right, I do like how that leaves the implementation up to the implementer, the thing I'd really like to do is provide flexibility in choosing whether or not there is an inverse_transform. Or perhaps something additional like a post inverse_filter.